# Dark Mode Flutter with shared preferences and provider

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I want to implement dark/light mode from settings page where a toggle switch is used, everything works good except when I select light mode and restart the app then the app reverts backs to dark mode. What am I doing wrong?

**Main.dart**

```
return MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => ThemeProvider()),
  ],
  child: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
    final themeProvider = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context);
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Unit Converter',
      home: const HomePage(),
      themeMode: themeProvider.themeMode,
      theme: MyThemes.lightTheme,
      darkTheme: MyThemes.darkTheme,
    );
  }),
);
```

**Themeprovider.dart**

```
class ThemeProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  ThemeMode themeMode = ThemeMode.dark;

  bool get isDarkMode => themeMode == ThemeMode.dark;

  void toggleTheme(bool isOn) {
    themeMode = isOn ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

**Setting_page.dart**

```
final themeProvider = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context);

SwitchListTile(
title: const Text('Dark Mode'),
                  value: themeProvider.isDarkMode,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    final provider =
                    Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context, listen: false);
                    provider.toggleTheme(value);
                  },
                ),
```

Comment: Save your currently stored theme in shared preferences while toggling the theme. and while opening the app, you need to check the theme stored in shared preferences and update the value of themeMode inside ThemeProvider. It'll work fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because, you haven't stored which theme is selected by user in shared preferences/other database locally. For doing what you're trying to do, you need to keep the theme user has selected currently in shared preferences while changing the theme, and while opening the app, you need to check which theme is selected by the user, and update the theme accordingly.
For this:

Update your `ThemeProvider` class like this

```
class ThemeProvider extends ChangeNotifier {

  ///This will get called at initial and check the theme you've currently stored. and update the theme initially.
  ThemeProvider() {
    getThemeAtInit();
  }

  
  getThemeAtInit() async{
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool? isDarkTheme =
        sharedPreferences.getBool("is_dark");
    if (isDarkTheme != null && isDarkTheme!) {
      themeMode = ThemeMode.dark;
    } else {
      themeMode = ThemeMode.light;
      }
      notifyListeners();
    }

  ThemeMode themeMode = ThemeMode.dark;

  bool get isDarkMode => themeMode == ThemeMode.dark;

  void toggleTheme(bool isOn) async{
        themeMode = isOn ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light;
        notifyListeners();
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        sharedPreferences.setBool("is_dark", themeMode == ThemeMode.dark) //Update this as per your condition.
      }
}
```

Do this and you're good to go.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! But there is still a minor problem. When I restart the app with darkmode switch off the app restarts in darkmode theme while the switch is off. When i toggle on the switch on and off again then only light mode gets activated.

Comment: Add notifyListeners() inside getThemeAtInit() function after setting the theme. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save your current theme in Local Storage (Shared Preferences). and Call the theme present in shared preference when app restart